# Calling multiple asynchronous requests to Thrift Service from a single client

Tags: java, asynchronous, thrift

For my Code it is necessary to call multiple asynchronous Requests from the same client to a Thrift Service.

So I am using a Non blocking Server and Asynchronous Clients (see the code below) to allow asynchronous Calls, which means the execution of the code continues after the first call of the "checkForPrime()" Method, which I call on the Thrift Service.
Now this seems to work with only executing one call. If I make a second asynchronous call right after, I get the following error message:

```
Client is currently executing another method: 
Interfaces.PrimeCheck$AsyncClient$checkForPrime_call
    at 
org.apache.thrift.async.TAsyncClient.checkReady(TAsyncClient.java:78)
    at 
Interfaces.PrimeCheck$AsyncClient.checkForPrime(PrimeCheck.java:110)
    at ThriftClient.main(ThriftClient.java:40)
```

I need a smart solution to allow for multiple calls, but it has to be from the same client. Any suggestions are welcome. Please dont hesitate if you need further information.

```java
        org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.Factory factory = new TBinaryProtocol.Factory();
        TAsyncClientManager manager;
        TNonblockingSocket socket;
        AsyncClient client;
        try {
            manager = new TAsyncClientManager();
            socket =new TNonblockingSocket("localhost", 4711);
            client = new AsyncClient(factory, manager, socket);
            client.checkForPrime(5, resultHandler);
            client.checkForPrime(7, resultHandler);
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (IOException e2) ....
```

Answer (score 2):

> to allow asynchronous Calls, which means the execution of the code continues after the first call of the "checkForPrime()" Method,

Not quite. **Asynchronous only means that [the call is completed asynchronously](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/lib/java/src/org/apache/thrift/async/TAsyncClient.java#L70) and you don't have to wait for the completion** until necessary.

It does **not** imply that you can use the same client to do another parallel request. Some implementations may support this but the current implementation does not.

Multiple outstanding calls require some bookkeeping, otherwise you will get lost with the responses:

```
 call 1 made --->
 call 2 made --->
 response arrives <----
 response arrives <----
```

Now, what call does the first response belong to: call 1 or call 2? Hard to say, it could be either one. Without more information a multi-call client would have a hard time trying to correlate the data.

The [TAsyncClientManager](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/lib/java/src/org/apache/thrift/async/TAsyncClientManager.java) handles that by restricting clients to allowing only one pending call at a time.

> it is necessary to call multiple asynchronous Requests from the same client

Why do you think it is necessary?

**The client is only a mediator, a means of transport.** If you send two emails, do you require the emails follow the exact same path across the [interwebs](https://xkcd.com/181/)? No, because the relevant information the other side (server) should rely on is in the message content, not in the transport level.

If, however, you need to store data at the client, you should store it in a dedicated place outside of the client instance. Either way, the fact that we deal with one or two client instances should not really matter.